# Unittesting class methods with class attribute (state)

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a class called `Connector`, which is supposed to dis/connect to a network device.

```
class Connector:
    def __init__(self) -> NoReturn:
        pass 

    def __connect(self, **kwargs) -> netmiko.ConnectHandler:
        handler = None
        try:
            device = {
                "device_type": kwargs["device_type"],
                "username": kwargs["username"],
                "password": kwargs["password"],
                "secret": kwargs["secret"],
            }

            if kwargs["connection_type"] == "serial":
                device['serial_settings'] = {'port': kwargs['port']}
            elif kwargs["connection_type"] == "ssh" or kwargs["connection_type"] == "telnet":
                keys = kwargs.keys()
                if "host" not in keys and 'ip' not in keys:
                    raise ValueError("Host and/or IP need to be specified")

                endpoint_type = 'host' if kwargs['host'] else 'ip' if kwargs['ip'] else None 
                endpoint = kwargs['host'] if kwargs['host'] else kwargs['ip'] if kwargs['ip'] else None
                device[endpoint_type] = endpoint
            else: 
                console_logger.info("Connection type needs to be either 'serial', 'ssh' or 'telnet'")
                raise ConnectionTypeError()
        except KeyError as e:
            console_logger.error(f"[!] {str(e)} is missing.")
        
        try:
            handler = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
        except ValueError as e:
            # If given value of key is invalid
            console_logger.error("[!]" + str(e))
        except TypeError as e:
            # if given key of dict config is invalid
            console_logger.error(f"[!] {str(e)} is missing.")
        except NetmikoTimeoutException as e:
            console_logger.info("[i] Connection timeout. Please check connection parameters and retry. More details in logs.")
            warning_logger.warning(f"[!] Connection timed-out. {str(e)}")
        except NetmikoAuthenticationException as e:
            console_logger.info("[i] Authentication failed. Please check credentials. More details in logs.")
            warning_logger.error(f"[!] Authentication failed: {str(e)}")
        except ConfigInvalidException as e: 
            console_logger.info("Configuration is invalid. Please check configuration settings. More details in logs.")
            warning_logger.error(f"Configuration is invalid: {str(e)}")
        except Exception as e:
            console_logger.error("[E] Failed to establish connection. More detail in logs.")
            warning_logger.error(f"Failed to establish connection: {str(e)}")
            raise

        return handler

    
    def open_connection(self, **kwargs) -> Union[netmiko.ConnectHandler, None]: 
        handler = None 
        if 'device_name' not in kwargs.keys():
            console_logger.error(f"[!] Key 'device_name' is missing.")
            return handler 

        handler = self.__connect(**kwargs)
        return handler

    def close_connection(self, handler: netmiko.ConnectHandler) -> None:
        handler.disconnect()
```

```
class TestConnector(unittest.TestCase):

    connection_arg_dict = {
        "device_name" : "test_device",
        "device_type": "cisco_ios_serial",
        "username": "",
        "password": "",
        "secret": "",
        "port": "ttyUSB0",
        "connection_type": "serial"
    }

    def setUp(self):
        self.connector = Connector()

    def test_open_connection(self):
        handler = self.connector.open_connection(**self.connection_arg_dict)
        assert handler is not None 

    def test_close_connection(self):
        """This is certainly not the way to go!"""
        handler = self.connector.open_connection(**self.connection_arg_dict)
        assert handler is not None 
        self.connector.close_connection(handler)
```

Now i want to write unit tests for it, but i am not sure about the how. Since one unit test should not depend on the other and surely it is not good practice to use an object  defined in another unit test or a method which was probably not tested yet since the tests could be called in a different order.

Is there any approach to a situation like this?

Comment: You need an open connection in order to test closing it, so I wouldn't bother with two seperate test methods. Write a single method that can fail if you can't open a connection as well as if you can't close the resulting open connection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had the idea but was not sure about it... I put more thought into this than necessary i think.